# Merge multiple column values in one column in one row Oracle SQL without losing the color formatting

Tags: sql, oracle

I have got multiple columns that needs to be merged into one column, but do not want to lose the color formatting for individual column cell

```html
Table name: report
colNum col1 col2 col3
1      a    b    c 
2      b    a    b 

All b are in red color
All a are in Green color
All c are in black color

After
ColNum NewCol
1     a b c
2     b a b

I have used the below query 
select colnum, col1||' '||col2||' '||col3 as NewCol
from report

Issue is color formatting is lost after the merge
```

After

Comment: The Oracle database does not store color for values, but data only. Please elaborate on the color aspect.

Comment: these 'a', 'b' 'c' are like legends. so by viewing the color of the text will show the data visually.  If this is not possible will try to see something else.

Comment: Maybe the values have some HTML tags/formatting you are not including?

Comment: It doesn't matter what the colors mean.  As @TheImpaler said, the database doesn't know anything about that. Colors of displayed text is something done by the application/client program.  And we don't know what that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others in the comments have stated, there is no color stored in the database with the data. The color that the information is displayed is dependent on the client you are using to query the data.

I do not believe that SQLPlus has any coloring options. If you are using SQLcl, Kris Rice (a developer of SQLcl) has a [blog post](https://krisrice.io/2019-04-18-SQLcl-SQLFormat/) showing how to do all kinds of coloring when using SQLcl as the client. SQL Developer coloring can be defined using HTML-style formatting as long as the column starts with the `<html>` tag (see screenshot below). Other development tools such as PL/SQL Developer and Toad likely have their own coloring options, but I am not familiar with them so you would have to look through their website/documentation.

#### Query for SQL Developer

```sql
WITH
    test_table (colNum,
                col1,
                col2,
                col3)
    AS
        (SELECT 1, 'a', 'b', 'c' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 2, 'b', 'a', 'b' FROM DUAL)
SELECT colnum, '<html><font size="5" color="red">'||col1 as col1,
               '<html><font size="5" color="green">'||col2 as col2,
               '<html><font size="5" color="black">'||col3 as col3,
               '<html><font size="5" color="red">'||col1
                  || '<font size="5" color="green"> ' || col2
                  || '<font size="5" color="black"> ' || col3 AS newcol
  FROM test_table;
```

#### SQL Developer 20.2 Result

[image: SQL Developer 20.2 screenshot with coloring example]